# Color Image to black and white conversion using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

This is the code I am using for color to grey scale image conversion.

```
        function grayScaleEffect() {
            var imageData = contextSrc.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            var data = imageData.data;

            var p1 = 0.99;
            var p2 = 0.99;
            var p3 = 0.99;
            var er = 0; // extra red
            var eg = 0; // extra green
            var eb = 0; // extra blue
            for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
                var grayscale = data[i] * p1 + data[i + 1] * p2 + data[i + 2] * p3;
                data[i] = grayscale + er; // red
                data[i + 1] = grayscale + eg; // green
                data[i + 2] = grayscale + eb; // blue
            }
            context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
            base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
```

On changing the slider value, image must change from color to black and white and vice versa.

It must be compatible for all browsers.

Is there some other way I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can add from css this effect and if you want to remove it, remove the css class to the image with javascript.

```
.black_and_white { 
            filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
            filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cbertelegni/vSu67/)

[Change class with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/cbertelegni/vSu67/2/)

[Change class with native javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/cbertelegni/vSu67/3/)

Comment: I think I can change the value for chrome and safari. How to do it in IE?

Comment: only you remove the class of the img. see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbertelegni/vSu67/2/

Comment: if you prefer native javascript see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbertelegni/vSu67/3/

Comment: Not working in ie. More over that i don't want to do this on a single click. Color should change on changing the slider value.

Comment: i have used this css filters and are native from IE and works in IE. How implement this for your task is other thing.